# ClassNotFoundException while connecting to Hive Remotely using Jdbc on Hortonworks

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I am facing this exception while connecting to beeline, hive2 version 1.2.1000.2.5.0.0, I have added hive-jdbc.jar file into classpath on my Windows 10 machine.

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:17)
```

**HiveJdbcClient.java**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {

  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10003/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
  }
}
```

1. I am not sure what other jars I need to add here?
2. These jar files change based on the version of Hive?
3. Does Cloudera and Hortonworks etc have different jar files, please visit this [page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc), this is so confusing.
4. Why it's so complicated to connect to Hive, I have my hive on Hortonworks, which is http://142.56.78.174:10003/default, and I have added hive-jdbc jar files to the classpath and I have my java class below. Isn't this enough?
5. Please let me know what I am really missing.

Thanks for the answer, I have already tried this,

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried my best on Windows couldn't run it successfully. So, I switched to centos, this should also help Windows users, do comment for any questions :)

It’s hard to find all the jars to 1.2.1000.2.5.0.0, so I tried 1.2.1 version and it worked on our nn2 server. I have wasted lot of time on Windows, Linux has a very good documentation.

**HiveJdbcClient.java:**

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {

  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws SQLException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
  }
}
```

Above is the simple program which I tried on our nn2, before you run any of those files, please add all these jars into the classpath of any machine which you are working on.

I hope I am not missing some jar files, this should work for you with no errors:

1. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-serde/1.2.1
2. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-common/1.2.1
3. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-shims/1.2.1
4. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-beeline/1.2.1
5. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec/1.2.1
6. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-metastore/1.2.1
7. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-service/1.2.1
8. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5
9. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.1
10. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.3-alpha1
11. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.4
12. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2
13. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.2.0
14. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21
15. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/1.2.1

If you just want to test the connection without adding into the classpath you can do it using this command on 
**Linux:**

Compile:

```
[root@centosserver ~]# javac -cp .:hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:hive-service-1.2.1.jar:hive-exec-1.2.1.jar:hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar:hive-shims-1.2.1.jar:hive-beeline-1.2.1:hive-serde-1.2.1:hive-common-1.2.1:httpclient-4.2.5.jar:httpcore-4.2.1.jar:httpcore-4.3-alpha1.jar:httpclient-4.0-alpha4.jar:httpclient-4.3.4.jar:commons-logging-1.2.jar:hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar HiveJdbcClient.java
```

**Execute:**

```
[root@centosserver ~]# java -cp .:hive-jdbc-1.2.1.jar:hive-service-1.2.1.jar:hive-exec-1.2.1.jar:hive-metastore-1.2.1.jar:hive-shims-1.2.1.jar:hive-beeline-1.2.1:hive-serde-1.2.1:hive-common-1.2.1:httpclient-4.2.5.jar:httpcore-4.2.1.jar:httpcore-4.3-alpha1.jar:httpclient-4.0-alpha4.jar:httpclient-4.3.4.jar:commons-logging-1.2.jar:hadoop-common-2.2.0.jar:slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar HiveJdbcClient
```

Basic command is

```
java -cp .:your-Jar-File1:your-Jar-File2:your-Jar-File3 yourMainClass.Java
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use the most recent jar ***(e.g version 2.1x)***
 you should try this

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
```

instead of

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
```

for in recent JDBC jar there is no ***`org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`***

Comment: Thanks I already tried this `private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";`